# how can i pass an array with ngx-translate in angular 7 a html property?

Tags: arrays, angular, properties, translate

how can i pass an Array with ngx-translate in Angular html template like this? (this isnt working)

```
<html-tag [prop]="[ {{ 'text' | translate }}, {{ 'text2' | translate }} ]">
</html-tag>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that work without the curly braces? Generally, you don't need them in a square bracket bindings, so have you tested:
[prop]="[ 'text' | translate,  'text2' | translate ]"

Comment: no, it dont pass the value with my json: { "text": "testText" } -> got empty

Comment: so, the empty field bug from another thing, if i wait a tick i get the data right. thank u your answer, its work.